# What is the difference between demand paging and page replacement?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, page-replacement, demand-paging

From what I understand, demand paging is basically paging with swapping, so you can swap in a page when it is needed. But page replacement seems like more or less the same thing, where you bring in a page is needed and switching it with an existing page in physical memory.

So is there a distinct difference?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Homework dump, same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876785/explain-frame-allocation-vs-page-replacement-algorithm-in-memory-management

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework dump, as revealed by later 'question': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876785/explain-frame-allocation-vs-page-replacement-algorithm-in-memory-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a system that uses demand paging, the operating system copies a disk page into physical memory only if an attempt is made to access it and that page is not already in memory (i.e., if a page fault occurs). It follows that a process begins execution with none of its pages in physical memory, and many page faults will occur until most of a process's working set of pages is located in physical memory. This is an example of a lazy loading technique.

From [Wikipedia's Demand paging:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging)

> Demand paging follows that *pages should only be brought into memory if
>   the executing process demands them*. This is often referred to as lazy
>   evaluation as *only those pages demanded by the process are swapped
>   from secondary storage to main memory*. *Contrast this to pure swapping,
>   where all memory for a process is swapped from secondary storage to
>   main memory during the process startup*.

Whereas, page replacement is simply the technique which is done when there occurs a page-fault. ***Page replacement is a technique which is utilised for both pure swapping and demand-paging.***

Comment: Think in this way :- page-replacement is used in both (Demand-Paging + Pure-swapping), whereas demand-paging is a specific-type.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Replacement** simply means swapping two processes between memory and disk.

**Demand Paging** is a concept in which only required pages are brought into the memory. In case where a page required is not in the memory, the system looks for free frames in the memory. If there are no free frames, then a page replacement is done to bring the required page from the disk to the memory.